# Typsescript project references, composite and allowJS

Tags: typescript, config, transpiler, project-reference

I want to be able to share code between a few Typescript projects.

```
ts-project
├── project1
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── somecode.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── project2
│   ├── somecode.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── shared
    ├── dist
    ├── index.ts
    ├── package.json
    ├── someothercode.js
    ├── somesharedcode.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

To transpile the code in `shared` I previously had `allowJS: true` so that `someothercode.js` was included in the tsc transpile step and all the code ended up in `dist/` and `package.json`'s `main` pointed to `dist/index.js`.

In `project1` in the `package.json` dependencies I have `"shared":"file:../shared"` and I can `import` the shared code as with a normal package.

So that the typescript compiler knows about the `shared` code `project1` `tsconfig.json` needs

```
   "references": [{
        "path": "../shared"
    }]
```

Now comes my problem that I need your help with.

For the project reference to work properly the `tsconfig` in `shared` needs a property

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
   }
```

But, with `composite: true` set I can no longer use `allowJS: true` which means the `someothercode.js` file is no longer included in the dist folder.

It is not currently possible to change all the `.js` code to `ts` (we are working on it!) so I need to be able to process both `ts` and `js` files but still need the IDE typescript support and be able to use `tsc -b`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Our team is starting to incrementally migrate an existing NodeJS project from JS to TS and I'd like to use `composite: true` too

Comment: @AmitBeckenstein, I did not get an answer. We eventually converted everything to typescript! (Great day). Sorry to be of no help :)

Comment: It seems that this is no longer a problem since TS3.7